# Compile errors trying to install WebRTCVAD module

Tags: python, windows, pip, webrtc

I'm trying to create an app that uses the WebRTC VAD code. 
I have found this: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/webrtcvad

The issue is that I cannot get it to work. 
I extract the content into a folder but when It ry to run something it complains that _webrtcvad module is missing.

After a little research I tried to install the webRTC VAD module through pip. When doing this inside the folder I extracted into I get this:

[image]

When trying in another directory this happens:
[image]

How do I get this to work?

Comment: This looks related to a bug (https://github.com/wiseman/py-webrtcvad/issues/1) that was fixed several months ago; the fix should be in version 2.0.8.  Sorry I don't use Windows enough to help more.  (Also, please don't post screenshots of error messages--copy & paste the text so that they're searchable and easier to read.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was a bug in my webrtcvad's `setup.py` that caused it to use the wrong flags when compiling for Windows: it was using `-DWEBRTC_POSIX` instead of `-DWIN32`.

The fixed version has been pushed to pypi as version 2.0.9.  I've confirmed that `pip install webrtcvad` works correctly on Windows 10.